# jQuery gallery - load image and then animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any possibility how to load an image with jQuery in background and than animate the transition? I have a gallery of big fullscreen images as a background for my website. I have paths of all images in some hidden elements, at first I make the background div bit transparent, than I change the background-image property with jQuery and at last I make it again visible..But there is a bit long time before the image is loaded. I dont want to show any loader or something else..I only want to load the image in background and than male the transition..Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: My code is something about $("div#background").fadeOut('slow') with callback function on the same element .css('background-image',next_image); and then again on the same element .fadeIn(slow)
In particular is it bit more complex,but it's good for example what I am looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try jquery image load

```
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/
```

Comment: Yeah it seems to be exactly what I am seeking..:)I am going to try it